# Excel: nested function problems (INDEX and IF)

Tags: excel-formula

Hi I am an excel novice and I am trying to search a table of postcodes matched to a cell with postcodes, to return a political Ward i.e. Pcode: W14 0HY- Ward:Addison. This works using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(WARDTABLE[[#Headers],[Addison]:[Fulham Broadway]],,SUMPRODUCT(('WARDS Table'!$A$2:$P$1147=[@Postcode])*COLUMN(WARDTABLE[[#All],[Addison]:[Fulham Broadway]])))
```

I also need two possible other outcomes, where the postcode field is blank, to return `Not Stated` this works using:

```
=IF(CS_DATA_18_21[@Postcode]="","Not Stated" )
```

and if a postcode contain a pcode that is out of borough and doesn't match the postcodes in the WARDTABLE to return "`Out of Borough`", this works using:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(WARDTABLE[#All],T2),,"OUT OF BOROUGH")
```

My problem is I cannot get all three to work together, I keep getting too many arguments error message, the problem is in trying to combine the Index and two IFs formulas.

I hope this makes sense, any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`=IFS(CS_DATA_18_21[@Postcode]="","Not Stated",COUNTIF(WARDTABLE[#All],T2)=0,"OUT OF BOROUGH", 1=1, INDEX(WARDTABLE[[#Headers],[Addison]:[Fulham Broadway]],,SUMPRODUCT(('WARDS Table'!$A$2:$P$1147=[@Postcode])*COLUMN(WARDTABLE[[#All],[Addison]:[Fulham Broadway]]))))`

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciate this!

Comment: @Ramuk Please mark it as an answer if it works for you - click the tick on the right.